# How can I lower my washing machine sound?

Tags: home

My washing machine got more and more lounder and shaking after I have been used 6 months .
So I like to lower machine sound and less shaking so what I need to put around the machine ?

Comment: Hi David, Welcome to Lifehacks. Is your washing machine a top loading model or a front-loading model? Please edit your question to include details as you do not have enough points to comment.

Answer (score 5):

Two common causes are weak vibration dampers or a failing tub bearing.
Look up the service manual for your washing machine online, and/or find service videos showing how to check and replace the parts.

Covering the machine will only reduce noise until the washer breaks from the vibration.

Comment: What the doctor said exactly. Fix this now; perhaps it’s still under warranty? If not, you will pay more to fix it later or replace it completely.

Comment: Another cause can be overloading the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Another common cause is not setting the machine up properly.

- The machine must be level, check using a spirit level. Adjust the feet if necessary.
- All 4 feet must be firmly in contact with the ground.

When the machine is not level or it rests on only 3 feet, it'll start walking around during spin-dry cycles.

Sometimes it helps to place the feet on rubber blocks.